# Copiar um numpy.array sem modificar o original

Tags: python, array, numpy

Dado um `numpy.array` como o a seguir:

```
r = np.arange(36)
r.resize(6, 6)
```

Que resulta em:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

Agora quando quero copiar apenas um pedaço desse array, como por exemplo:

```
r2 = r[:3,:3]
```

Que resulta em:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

Se modifico o array `r2` então o array `r` também é modificado:

```
r2[:] = 0
```

Agora o array r é:

```
[[ 0  0  0  3  4  5]
 [ 0  0  0  9 10 11]
 [ 0  0  0 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
```

Então gostaria de saber como copiar `r2` de modo que se eu o modifique, não altere o array original `r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve fazer uma cópia para que `r2` para que não aponte para o mesmo objecto:

```
import numpy

r = numpy.arange(36)
r.resize(6,6)
r2 = numpy.copy(r[:3,:3])
r2[:] = 0
```

Fazendo `print(r)` o output vai ser:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
```

E o output de `print(r2)`:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Como pode ver pode "mexer" à vontade em `r2` sem que `r` seja afetado.

[DOCUMENTAÇÂO numpy.copy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html)

Relacionado: http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php